# Kubernetes executor and private docker images in apache airflow deployed in Kubernetes not working

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow

I have deployed apache airflow in azure kubernetes.

Helm repository of apache airflow: https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/chart

AKS version: 1.16.13

I am reading the dags in my GitHub with git-sync, for that, I have modified the values.yml file:

```yml
dags:
  persistence:
    # Enable persistent volume for storing dags
    enabled: false
    # Volume size for dags
    size: 1Gi
    # If using a custom storageClass, pass name here
    storageClassName:
    # access mode of the persistent volume
    accessMode: ReadWriteMany
    ## the name of an existing PVC to use
    existingClaim: ~
  gitSync:
    enabled: true
    # git repo clone url
    # ssh examples ssh://git@github.com/apache/airflow.git
    # git@github.com:apache/airflow.git
    # https example: https://github.com/apache/airflow.git
    repo: https://my_github_repository.git
    branch: master
    rev: HEAD
    root: "/git"
    dest: "repo"
```

Once I have airflow deployed I have tested it with this dag:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'kubernetes_sample', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10))


start = DummyOperator(task_id='run_this_first', dag=dag)

passing = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
                          image="python:3.8-slim-buster",
                          cmds=["python3","-c"],
                          arguments=["print('hello world')"],
                          labels={"foo": "bar"},
                          name="passing-test",
                          task_id="passing-task",
                          get_logs=True,
                          dag=dag
                          )


passing.set_upstream(start)
```

It works fine. Now I want to use my own images. For that, I am using azure containers, and following this  guide: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/kubernetes.html, I am using this code to create the secret to access to my azure registry:

```sh
kubectl create secret docker-registry testquay \
    --docker-server=quay.io \
    --docker-username=<Profile name> \
    --docker-password=<password>
```

I build my image and I test locally and it is working. I upload the image to azure container registry and I write the following dag:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s
import logging
import os
import sys
import traceback 

try:

    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
        'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
    }

    dag = DAG(
        'test1', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10))


    start = DummyOperator(task_id='run_this_first', dag=dag)

    quay_k8s = KubernetesPodOperator(
            namespace='default',
            image='<MY_SERVER_NAME>/testingairlfowdags:latest',
            image_pull_secrets=[k8s.V1LocalObjectReference('azure-registry')],
            name="testingairlfowdags",
            is_delete_operator_pod=True,
            in_cluster=True,
            task_id="task-two",
            get_logs=True,
            log_events_on_failure = True,
            dag=dag
        )

    start >> quay_k8s

except Exception as e:

    error_message = {
            "message": "An internal error ocurred"
            ,"error": str(e)
            , "error information" : str(sys.exc_info())
            , "traceback": str(traceback.format_exc())
        }
    logging.info(error_message)
```

But when the quay_k8s task starts a pod is created and suddenly killed, I cannot get any log.

The Kubernetes dashboard shows me this when the pod is initialised:
[image]

But then:

[image]

Comment: did you happen to find out the reason for this?

Comment: Yes,
image_pull_secrets='azure-registry'